# method readLine() from the type DataInputStream is deprecated

Tags: java, user-input, deprecated, readline, datainputstream

I have this Java code for Chat-Client
in which the DataInputStream is,is defined like this:

```
private static DataInputStream is=null;
```

And I keep getting error on this part:

```
public void run() {
/*
 * Keep on reading from the socket of the server    
 */
 String responseLine; //used to implement reading from the socket
 try{
     while((responseLine=is.readLine())!=null){ //when we recieve messages we print out here
         System.out.println(responseLine); // "is" is the object of data input stream
     }
     closed=true;
 }catch(IOException e){
     System.out.println("IOException: "+e);
 }


}
```

everytime I try to fix it using the information on the javadoc :

```
Deprecated. This method does not properly convert bytes to characters. As of JDK 1.1, the preferred way to read lines of text is via the BufferedReader.readLine() method. Programs that use the DataInputStream class to read lines can be converted to use the BufferedReader class by replacing code of the form:

DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(in);
```

with:

```
BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

I get another error in the code on this line:

```
 is=new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
```

How can I fix this?I would appreciate any help I can get on this matter

the Class Client code:

public class Clientt implements Runnable {//first we implement chat client

```
//the client socket        //sience we have multiple clients we are implementing threading in our application 
private static Socket clientSocket=null;
//the output stream
private static PrintStream os=null; //initializing the input & output streams
//the input stream
private static DataInputStream is=null;

private static BufferedReader inputLine=null;
private static boolean closed=false;
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    //the default port
    int portNumber=5000;
    //the default host
    String host="localhost";

    if(args.length<2)
    {
        System.out.println("Usage:Java Client <host> <portNumber>\n"
                +"now using host="+host+",portNumber="+portNumber);
    }
    else
    {
        host=args[0];
        portNumber=Integer.valueOf(args[1]).intValue();
    }

    /* 
     * Open a socket on a given host and port.
     * Open input and Output streams
     */

    try{
        clientSocket=new Socket(host,portNumber); //initializing clientsocket with mentioned host and port num
        inputLine=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));//read input from the user using inputLine
        os=new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());//outputstream is used to write to socket
        is=new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());// inputstream is uset to read from socket
    }catch(UnknownHostException e){
        System.err.println("Don't know about host"+host);
    }catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for connection to the host"+host);
      }
    /*
     * If everything has been initialized then we want to write some date 
     * to the socket we have opened a connection to on the port portNumber
     */

    if(clientSocket!=null && os!=null && is!=null)
    {
        try{
            //Creat a thread to read from the server
            new Thread(new Clientt()).start(); //here we implement threading
            while(!closed)
            {
                os.println(inputLine.readLine());//loop continues infinetely untill we terminate application and writes to socket using output stream object
            }
            /*
             * Close the output stream,close the input stream,close the socket
             */
            os.close();
            is.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IOException: "+e);

        }
    }

}

/*
 * Creat thread to read from the server
 * 
 */

//@Override

public void run() {
/*
 * Keep on reading from the socket of the server    
 */
 String responseLine; //used to implement reading from the socket
 try{
     while((responseLine=is.readLine())!=null){ //when we recieve messages we print out here
         System.out.println(responseLine); // "is" is the object of data input stream
     }
     closed=true;
 }catch(IOException e){
     System.out.println("IOException: "+e);
 }


}
```

}

Comment: Can you please, post the error you are getting the initialization of the the DataInputStream.

Ideally, what you want to do, is to pass this stream into a BufferedReader and then use the .lines() method to get everything. This way you'll avoid using a loop to iterate over each one.

Comment: About your example code, you mention variables `d`, `in` and `is` but it's not clear how they work together. I figure `d` and `is` are probably the same? Can you clarify that for us? Also the complete class file would help to get a picture of the whole situation.

Comment: @Quota I've edited the post with the code,hope this makes sense now

Comment: @Aris I get the "method readLine() from the type DataInputStream is deprecated",this line simply won't work so I can't get the program work properly

Comment: @Aris Is the stream (returned by `lines()`) going to loop over the lines immediately (i.e. as the come in)? If it waited for EOF before executing the loop it wouldn't be much of a use for a chat software.

Comment: @Liana Replacing the `DataInputStream` with a `BufferedReader` works perfectly fine for me--at least the compile part (I haven't run the program, obviously). You said that the line with `in=new DataInputStream(...)` still causes a problem after you implemented the `BufferedReader`: Have you by chance just forgotten to remove that line so the compiler reports an unknown variable? (Of course you want _all_ appearances of `is` replaced by your `BufferedReader` variable.) Otherwise please add the error message here so we can help you figuring out the problem.

Comment: @Liana. lines() provided by the BuffererdRead will return you a stream of strings. 

You can then collect this and add it into a List<String>. There is no need to loop in order to do as the method provided will take care of this. I do not understand what you mention about the EOF. In any way you can do something like this (assuming you would like to print out the outcome).

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        reader.lines().forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: @Quota  when I change the  `is=new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());` to `is=new BufferedReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());` I get  "The constructor BufferedReader(InputStream) is undefined"

Comment: @Liana, as mentioned in my comment you need to do the following:

BufferedRead br =  new BufferedRead(new InputStreamRead(stream)

you cannot just pass the DataInputStream into the BufferedReader.

Comment: @Aris I've tried to do it but I'm just having a hard time understanding how to

Comment: @liana What do you mean? The comment contains the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have difficulties correctly applying the `BufferedReader` instead of the `DataInputStream`. You need to glue the `BufferedReader` and the original input stream together using an `InputStreamReader`.

Try the following changes:

First the variable definition:

```
//private static DataInputStream is=null;
private static BufferedReader br=null;
```

Then the instantiation:

```
//is=new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());//...
br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
```

And finally wherever you have `is` you basically change to `br` (because the other used methods like `close()` and `readLine()` exist in both `DataInputStream` and `BufferedReader`).

Comment: should I keep it `responseLine=br.readLine())!=null`? I don't get anymore errors but for some reason it still won't work

Comment: Yes, `br.readLine()` is the non-deprecated counterpart to `is.readLine()`. For why it does not work, you'll have to debug by yourself... I guess you're talking about _running_ the program now (compared to _compiling_ it as in your original question).

Comment: For the record: I tried the program using `netcat` as counterpart and it works just fine: I can send and receive texts with your program.